# 'BpeTrainer' object cannot be converted to 'Sequence' when training Bpetokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

I found this class on

```
import os
from tokenizers.models import BPE
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.decoders import ByteLevel as ByteLevelDecoder
from tokenizers.normalizers import NFKC, Sequence
from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import ByteLevel
from tokenizers.trainers import BpeTrainer

class BPE_token(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokenizer = Tokenizer(BPE())
        self.tokenizer.normalizer = Sequence([
            NFKC()
        ])
        self.tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = ByteLevel()
        self.tokenizer.decoder = ByteLevelDecoder()

    def bpe_train(self, paths):
        trainer = BpeTrainer(vocab_size=50000, show_progress=True, inital_alphabet=ByteLevel.alphabet(), special_tokens=[
            "<s>",
            "<pad>",
            "</s>",
            "<unk>",
            "<mask>"
        ])
        self.tokenizer.train(trainer, paths)

    def save_tokenizer(self, location, prefix=None):
        if not os.path.exists(location):
            os.makedirs(location)
        self.tokenizer.model.save(location, prefix)
```

But when I try to use it like this

```
from tokenise import BPE_token
from pathlib import Path
import os
# the folder 'text' contains all the files
paths = [str(x) for x in Path("./text/").glob("**/*.txt")]
tokenizer = BPE_token()
# train the tokenizer model
tokenizer.bpe_train(paths)
# saving the tokenized data in our specified folder 
save_path = 'tokenized_data'
tokenizer.save_tokenizer(save_path)
```

I get the error in the train function where it says

TypeError: argument 'files': 'BpeTrainer' object cannot be converted to 'Sequence'

Now I am new to this topic and am not rly sure how to fix this problem or what mistake I made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this problem change value `self.tokenizer.train(trainer, paths)` to `self.tokenizer.train(paths, trainer)`